# Average in $lookup from multiple fields

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two schemas

```
export interface IRating extends Document {
user?: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
company?: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
email: string;
userRole: string;
userEmploymentStatus?: string;
userDepartment: string;
headline: string;
companyCulture: number;
companyInternalCommunication: number;
companyTeamwork: number;
companyWorkLifeBalance: number;
companySupportFromTheManagement: number;
companyFreedomOfIndependentWork: number;
diversityInclusiveOrDiverse: number;
diversityGenderEquality: number;
diversityAttitudeTowardsOderColleagues: number;
workEnvOffice: number;
workEnvFriendliness: number;
workEnvHandicappedAccess: number;
workEnvSafety: number;
careerCompensationForWork: number;
careerJobSecurity: number;
careerCompanyImage: number;
careerDevelopment: number;
careerChallengingWork: number;
suggestionsForImprovement: string;
likedStuffAboutCompany: string;
dislikedStuffAboutCompany: string;
recommendation: boolean;
benefits: string[];}
```

```
export interface ICompany extends Document {
    creatorId?: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
    ratings?: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }];
    creatorEmail: string;
    name: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    industryType: string;
    deletedAt?: Date | null;
}
```

I want to accomplish to get all companies with average score of their ratings. As you can see, one company can have more ratings.

Currently I have this snippet

```
Company.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup:
                        {
                            from: "ratings",
                            localField: "ratings",
                            foreignField: "_id",
                            as: "ratings"
                        },
                }

            ]);
```

But of course, this one returns only a JOIN on two collections. I need to get average of all number filed's in Rating collection.

*****EDIT*****
After a little bit of research, I managed to write this.

```
Company.aggregate([
               {
                   $lookup:
                       {
                           from: "ratings",
                           localField: "ratings",
                           foreignField: "_id",
                           as: "ratings"
                       },
               },
               {
                   $addFields: {
                       averagePerDocument: {
                           $map:
                               {
                                   input: "$ratings",
                                   as: "rating",
                                   in: {$avg:["$$rating.companyCulture","$$rating.companyInternalCommunication",
                                           "$$rating.companyTeamwork", "$$rating.companyWorkLifeBalance",
                                           "$$rating.companySupportFromTheManagement", "$$rating.companyFreedomOfIndependentWork",
                                           "$$rating.diversityInclusiveOrDiverse", "$$rating.diversityGenderEquality",
                                           "$$rating.diversityAttitudeTowardsOderColleagues", "$$rating.workEnvOffice",
                                           "$$rating.workEnvFriendliness", "$$rating.workEnvHandicappedAccess", "$$rating.workEnvSafety",
                                           "$$rating.careerCompensationForWork", "$$rating.careerJobSecurity", "$$rating.careerCompanyImage",
                                           "$$rating.careerDevelopment", "$$rating.careerChallengingWork"]}
                               }
                       }
                   }
               }
           ]);
```

This one returns me this. (Note that I haven't pasted whole JSON)

```
 "averagePerDocument": [
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    2.9444444444444446,
    1,
    5
  ]
```

Now I need only average to be shown in one field out of those values.

**Update again.** Sorry, I guess that I can think better when there is a beer near me.
I just used projection

```
Company.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup:
                        {
                            from: "ratings",
                            localField: "ratings",
                            foreignField: "_id",
                            as: "ratings"
                        },
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        averagePerDocument: {
                            $map:
                                {
                                    input: "$ratings",
                                    as: "rating",
                                    in: {$avg:["$$rating.companyCulture","$$rating.companyInternalCommunication",
                                            "$$rating.companyTeamwork", "$$rating.companyWorkLifeBalance",
                                            "$$rating.companySupportFromTheManagement", "$$rating.companyFreedomOfIndependentWork",
                                            "$$rating.diversityInclusiveOrDiverse", "$$rating.diversityGenderEquality",
                                            "$$rating.diversityAttitudeTowardsOderColleagues", "$$rating.workEnvOffice",
                                            "$$rating.workEnvFriendliness", "$$rating.workEnvHandicappedAccess", "$$rating.workEnvSafety",
                                            "$$rating.careerCompensationForWork", "$$rating.careerJobSecurity", "$$rating.careerCompanyImage",
                                            "$$rating.careerDevelopment", "$$rating.careerChallengingWork"]}
                                }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id:1,
                        name:1,
                        test: {
                            $avg:['$averagePerDocument']
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]);
```